# Can duplicated objects be given a separate material?

Tags: materials

I duplicated a model, but when I change color of one of the duplicated models, they both change color. I tried looking up how to separate them to color them differently but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Link your material to **Object** instead of object data. This drop menu is in the picture. By default it is set to Data

[image]

If you do it you need to set a new material.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also create a single user copy of your material.**

If you go to the Properties panel and select the Material tab, the amount of "users" (objects) of your material is displayed in the material selector. Click on this number to create a single copy of this material that you now can change to your liking.

Blender 2.79:

[image: create single user copy in Blender 2.79]

Blender 2.80:

[image: create single user copy in Blender 2.80]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as [accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)